# Asp.Net Web Api 2 Json deserialization parsing unquoted character

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to understand a deserialization quirk around an invalid json request when trying to set a double with unquoted values. Given the example controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Foo foo)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Foo    
{
    public string StringOne { get; set; }

    public double Bah { get; set; }

    public string StringTwo { get; set; }
}
```

The valid case with a JSON object such as:

```
{
   "StringOne": "Lorem",
   "Bah" : 1.2,
   "StringTwo" : "Ipsum" 
}
```

will build a foo object as you would expect, setting all three values correctly. The following invalid JSON will result in foo being set to null. Again this seems expected

```
{
   "StringOne": "Lorem",
   "Bah" : ThisIsntRight,
   "StringTwo" : "Ipsum" 
}
```

However when the following JSON is used

```
{
   "StringOne": "Lorem",
   "Bah" : Q,
   "StringTwo" : "Ipsum" 
}
```

foo is deserialized and Bah has a value of 0. I expected this to behave like the second example and to have foo set to null. I was hoping to understand what is going on in this case.

Note: This was recreated with the default empty web.api project and adding the above Controller.

Comment: Have you tried `decimal` instead of `double`?

Comment: `decimal` has the same behaviour

Comment: What happens if you send two letters? could it be because it tries to parse it as a char?

Comment: Two letters will return a null object. So some char related magic seems like a good bet